# Sharepoint Server 2007 generates event log entry every 5 minutes - "The SSP Timer Job Distribution List Import Job was not run."

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I get the following error logged into the Event Log every 5 minutes:

**The SSP Timer Job Distribution List Import Job was not run.
Reason: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer**

In addition, OWSTimer.exe periodically gets into a state where its consuming almost all the CPU and only killing the process or restarting the Sharepoint services fixes it (although I'm not sure if this is a related or seperate issue).

I have tried the following (based on various suggestions floating around the web), all to no avail:

- iisreset   (no affect)
- Added the Sharepoint and Sharepoint Search service accounts to Log on as a batch job and Log on as a service policies in the Group Policies for the domain.  I went into the Local Computer Policy on the Sharepoint server and verified that those policies had actually been applied
- Verified that the Sharepoint and Sharepoint Search service accounts are both in the WSS_WPG group
- Verified in dcomcnfg that the WSS_WPG group (and indeed the Sharepoint and Sharepoint search service accounts) has local activation rights for SPSearch.

Any more suggestions would be valued.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This article on TechNet provides a few additional items that you'll need to check:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/e8b34a19-c9d4-49ae-9015-33f9c0eedf3d